# Error thrown as Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: sql

Subquery returns more than 1 row, in `concat` operation syntax is wrong, I cannot able to identify the syntax error

```
select case when a.log_type='Schedule'
then  (select replace(concat(c.leadbank_name,'\n',time(b.schedule_time),'\n',b.schedule_type,'\n',b.schedule_remarks,'\n'),'\n','<br />')
from crm_trn_tschedulelog b
   where b.log_gid=a.log_gid)
    when a.log_type='Call Log'
then  (select replace(concat(c.leadbank_name,'\n','Person',' @ ',c.mobile_number,' on ',
     cast(DATE_FORMAT(c.call_date,'%d-%m-%Y') as char),'\n',c.remarks),'\n','<br />')
      from crm_trn_tcalllog c where c.log_gid=a.log_gid)  when a.log_type='Meeting'
then  (select replace(concat(c.leadbank_name,'\n','Mr/Ms ', d.fieldvisit_contactperson,
      ' at ', d.fieldvisit_location,' on ',  cast(DATE_FORMAT(d.fieldvisit_date,'%d-%m-%Y') as char),
      ' for ',(concat(d.fieldvisit_hour,':',fieldvisit_minute,':00')),' Hours ','\n',d.fieldvisit_remarks),'\n','<br />')
       from crm_trn_tfieldlog d where d.log_gid=a.log_gid)
        when a.log_type='Mail Log'
       then  (select cast(replace (concat(date_format(i.sent_date,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s %p'),'\n',
       i.sender_emailid,'\n',i.subject,'\n'),'\n','<br />') as char)  from acc_trn_temails i where i.log_gid=a.log_gid)  end as log_details,
         case when a.log_type='Schedule' then (select case when e.schedule_type='Call Log' then
         concat(d.user_firstname,' ',d.user_lastname,' ','Scheduled a Call On',' ', date_format(e.schedule_date,'%d-%m-%Y'))
          when e.schedule_type='Meeting'
          then concat(d.user_firstname,' ',d.user_lastname,' ','Scheduled a Meeting  On', ' ',
          date_format(e.schedule_date,'%d-%m-%Y')) when e.schedule_type='Mail Log'
          then concat(d.user_firstname,' ',d.user_lastname,' ','Scheduled Mail On',' '
          ,date_format(e.schedule_date,'%d-%m-%Y')) end  from crm_trn_tschedulelog e where e.log_gid=a.log_gid)
           when a.log_type='Call Log' then (select cast(concat(g.user_firstname,' ',g.user_lastname,' ','Called') as char)
             from crm_trn_tcalllog f left join adm_mst_tuser g on f.called_by = g.user_gid where f.log_gid = a.log_gid)
             when a.log_type='Meeting' then (select cast(concat(h.fieldvisit_contactperson2,' ','Met') as char)
             from crm_trn_tfieldlog h where h.log_gid=a.log_gid)

               when a.log_type='Mail Log'
              then  (select cast(concat('Mail Sent By ',g.user_firstname,' ',g.user_lastname) as char)
               from crm_trn_tlog f  left join adm_mst_tuser g on f.log_by = g.user_gid where f.log_gid = a.log_gid)
               end as log_legend, a.leadbank_gid,e.leadbankcontact_gid,f.campaign_gid,f.lead2campaign_gid  from crm_trn_tlog a
                 left join hrm_mst_temployee b on a.log_by=b.user_gid  left join adm_mst_tuser d on a.log_by=d.user_gid
                  left join crm_trn_tleadbank c on a.leadbank_gid=c.leadbank_gid
                  left join crm_trn_tleadbankcontact e on c.leadbank_gid=e.leadbank_gid
                   LEFT JOIN CRM_TRN_TLEAD2CAMPAIGN f on a.reference_gid=f.lead2campaign_gid
                    where b.employee_gid in('SERM1509230001','SERM1509230005','SERM1509230004','SERM1509230006',
                    'SERM1510130002','SERM1510130003','SERM1510150004','SERM1510150005','SERM1509230002','1') and
                    a.log_date BETWEEN CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND CURDATE()  order by a.log_gid desc ;
```

Comment: Please format your code. As for your question, I'm not surprised you can't identify where the problem lies.

Comment: Your tags are self-contradictory: if you're using vb.net, then you are not using asp-classic, and vice versa. And if that's how your code is, uh, "formatted" in real life, then figuring out where any bugs lie would take a minor miracle.

Comment: Also it it pays to actually identify the version of SQL you are using if the question is about a SQL query.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There's a clear syntax error here:

```
a.log_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND CURDATE()
```

What is it that you're trying to do with that portion of the where clause?

Comment: I think there are some DBMS that accept that non-standard interval syntax. In standard SQL it would be something like `between current_date - interval '7' day and current_date`